# Как правильно печатать из коллекции документ?

Tags: c#, wpf, печать

Я использовал **PrintVisual** чтобы с **ItemsControl** напечатать документ, проблема в том что он не переносит на другую страницу, если не помещается, и если пользователь прокрутит до середины или вниз, так и будет напечатано.

Я не могу понять в чем проблема. У меня принтер **Canon MF3010**.

Обязательно в наличии иметь электронный документ такой как например:doc чтобы корректно напечатать или можно напечатать нормально из контейнера ItemsControl?

Я гуглил ничего не помогло:

[How to Print Preview when using a DocumentPaginator to print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584551/how-to-print-preview-when-using-a-documentpaginator-to-print)

[WPF DocumentViewer Find-function and FixedPage documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183249/wpf-documentviewer-find-function-and-fixedpage-documents,)

[How to print multiple WPF pages in one document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138948/how-to-print-multiple-wpf-pages-in-one-document)

[C# создание и печать файла-тоже не подходит как там печататься одельные grids](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706253/c-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0/706258#706258)

[Ресурс professorweb с которого я узнал как печатать в wpf тоже криво печатает(не так как примерах например:где было надо напечатать текст обрезался с правой части,с фигурами еще хуже их откидывало в левый край после Трансформации)](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/documents_WPF/level28/28_9.php)

Идеи не знаю как реализовать:

**Алгоритм №1**

1) Подгонять **ItemsControl**  под размеры А4 листа,в примерах есть там код как сделать,код не работает:
`var pageSize = new Size(8.26 * 96, 11.69 * 96); // A4 page, at 96 dpi` и другие способы.

2)Если не удалось поместить на страницу поместить другую страницу.

3)Печать.

**Алгоритм №2**

1) Сохранить все данные из словаря в документ  типа doc.

2) Потом уже напечатать сам документ.

Код с#

```
private void Print()
{
    PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
    if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        printDialog.PrintVisual(ICTraining, "Распечатываем элемент Canvas");
    }
}
```

Код Xaml

```
<Grid Background =" White" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="305*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="13*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer   VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ItemsControl  Name="ICTraining">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="389*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Padding="5" Text="{Binding Key}"  FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />

                        <ItemsControl   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value}" Grid.Row="1" >
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>

                                    <Grid >
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="21*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="110*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Grid.Column="0"  Margin="1"   Width="190" Height="150"/>

                                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" >
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="554*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="111*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="217*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="64*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="217*"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15"   Margin="15,0,0,0" x:Name="ExerciseName" Text="{Binding Name}"/>



                                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,0,0,0">
                                                <TextBlock    FontSize="15"   Margin="5,0,0,0"  Text="Подход"/>
                                                <TextBlock    FontSize="15"   Margin="5,0,0,0"  Text="{Binding Amount}"/>
                                                <TextBlock    FontSize="15"   Margin="5,0,0,0"  Text="по"/>
                                                <TextBlock    FontSize="15"   Margin="5,0,0,0"  Text="{Binding Сount}"/>
                                                <TextBlock    FontSize="15"   Margin="6,0,0,0"  Text="{Binding Designation}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>

                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button Click="btnPrintOnClick" Grid.Row="1" Content="Печать" />
</Grid>
```

Как это выглядит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат печати
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Или расчитывать вручную по размерах влазит или нет или сохранять в ворд и потом уже печатать из него. Ворд сам распределяет обьекты по размерах на страницах что бы не обрезались.

Comment: @Andrew  Как я понял будет  проще  сохранять в word данные  из ItemsControl а потом напечатать,тогда буду рить в эту строну спасибо вам.

Comment: @Andrew как можно из ItemsControl  сохранить в word?

Comment: есть же некий прибиндженый соурс с данными. Вот оттуда данные нужные и вытягивать, а потом вставлять в ворд. Только бери какую-то готовую библиотеку заточенную под работу с вордом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Обязательно в наличии иметь электронный документ такой как например:doc чтобы корректно напечатать или можно напечатать нормально из контейнера ItemsControl?

Напечатать элемент UI "как есть" может и можно, но это не лучший путь. Качественно на страницы не разбить. См. например: [Есть ли возможность разрыва таблицы DataGrid WPF для разделения её на несколько таблиц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/960759/240512)

Вместо этого лучше сформировать документ для печати специальными средствами API [System.Windows.Documents](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents?view=netcore-3.1). Например как-то так для коллекции, состоящей из изображения и текстовой строки:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {       
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        const string path = "C:\\Test\\Images\\test.jpg";

        public static FlowDocument CreateDocument(List<Foo> list)
        {
            FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();            
            Table t;
            TableCell cell;
            TableRow trow;

            foreach (Foo item in list)
            {
                //добавим таблицу из одной строки
                t = new Table();                
                t.Columns.Add(new TableColumn());
                t.Columns.Add(new TableColumn());
                trow = new TableRow();

                //первый столбец - изображение
                cell = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new InlineUIContainer(item.Img)));
                trow.Cells.Add(cell);

                //второй столбец-строка
                cell = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(item.Name)));
                trow.Cells.Add(cell);

                var rows = new TableRowGroup();
                t.RowGroups.Add(rows);
                rows.Rows.Add(trow);
                fd.Blocks.Add(t);
            }

            return fd;
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<Foo> items = new List<Foo>();

            //сгенерируем тестовые данные
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Image img = new Image();
                img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));
                img.Height = 100;
                items.Add(new Foo { Img = img, Name = "item " + i.ToString() });
            }

            //создадим документ
            FlowDocument fd = CreateDocument(items);

            PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
            if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                //зададим параметры страницы
                fd.PageHeight = printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight;
                fd.PageWidth = printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth;
                fd.PagePadding = new Thickness(25);
                fd.ColumnGap = 0;
                fd.ColumnWidth = (fd.PageWidth - fd.PagePadding.Left - fd.PagePadding.Right);

                //печать
                IDocumentPaginatorSource dps = fd;
                printDialog.PrintDocument(dps.DocumentPaginator, "My document");
            }
        }

    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public Image Img { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Так выглядит результат (при печати на тестовом принтере, сохраняющем в PDF):

[image: document]

Comment: Спасибо вам, я находил много примеров  не 1 подошел ,даже через реализацию своего  DocumentPaginator там в коде были ошибки https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21951054/how-can-i-print-a-collection-of-usercontrols-in-wpf.

Comment: Как добавить заголовок виде дня как у меня на картинке ?

Comment: @Vladimir `fd.Blocks.Add( new Paragraph(new Run("День ..."));` По необходимости у Paragraph задать TextAlignment, если нужно его по центру.

Comment: @ MSDN.WhiteKnight Спасибо вам огромное за помощь,еще один вопрос можно как-то  сделать возле 2 столба внизу надпись  "подход 3 по 5 раз" из класса как на моей картинке.

Comment: @Vladimir Поместите внутрь TableCell элемент [Section](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.section?view=netframework-4.8) вместо Paragraph. В Section.Blocks можно добавить несколько элементов Paragraph, чтобы создать надписи одна под другой. Ну, или просто использовать Table с несколькими строками. С помощью Table и Section в документе можно построить любое дерево элементов, по аналогии с Grid и StackPanel в UI.

Comment: @ MSDN.WhiteKnight  Спасибо все идеально.

Comment: @Vladimir интересно, почему вы не приняли этот ответ?